# Multiple Instances of Varnish on single server

Tags: linux, varnish, varnish-vcl

I wan to run multiple instances of varnish on single server and each instance will work for each website, one wp, another drupal and joomla, etc. So i want ability to create multiple VLCs for each site. I can purge cache from all backends once I get this to work. Please help with this. Linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you create multiple VHOSTS in Varnish.

https://www.varnish-software.com/blog/virtual-hosts-varnish

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already saw that tried to do it, forgive me, I am not good at this, just trying to replicate solutions found on web. Little guidance here would be appreciated. I tried same thing, but I am going wrong with VCL creation in this scenario where I I redirect to different VCL depending on host. Can you tell me how these VCL should look like, i.e, should they contain backend informatino again? I need a sample VCL for vhost.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/default/varnish

it has the ability to have different listening IP:port combinations and seperate VCLs.

Ideal if you have WordPress on 1.1.1.1:80
and drupal on 1.1.1.2:80 
etc etc

why ? this will have you NOT mix up various rules for Drupal/WordPress etc.. in one VCL.
You can have /etc/varnish/wordpressrules.vcl  , /etc/varnish/drupalrules.vcl etc..

(you can even include general vcl's in your xrules.vcl)